# How to use `truncate` in PostgreSQL as we do in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, phpmyadmin

I want to empty a table in PostgreSQL but in the same way as we do in phpMyAdmin by using `truncate` command.

For example, if there are 4 records in the table then if we truncate the table then the new entry will be inserted with the index 1, but in PostgreSQL it stores the data with index 5.

Comment: Try http://topnew.net/sidu to truncate postgres tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the `RESTART IDENTITY` clause to `TRUNCATE`.

```
TRUNCATE mytable RESTART IDENTITY;
```

Answer (score 1):

Run following query to reset the the sequence number of column.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE [table_name]_[column_name]_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

Where replace `[table_name]` with your table name and `[column_name]` with the name of the column.

E.g if your table name is **department** and column name is **id** then your query might look something like this,

```
ALTER SEQUENCE department_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```